# Change background color on runtime

Tags: android, themes, background-color

I am working on an android application which is sort of an e-reader but it reads xml files. What I want it to change the background color of the xml file views using a change background button. Quite similar to what Kindle app where when reading an ebook, you can switch the background color to black, white or sepia. I believe this will require changing the whole theme rather than just the background as the text color will also change.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a theme at the runtime is not possible - you'll have to restart the current Activity and it will use the new Theme.

You can change the background for the Layout and the TextViews by iterating over the views and setting the colors yourself.

If you want to use the Theming method you must do the following:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
myActivity.startActivity(new Intent(myActivity.this, myActivity.class));
myActivity.finish();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am looking for a functionality similar to what kindle android app offer. While reading an ebook, cliking the menu button (touch or hardware) opens up a list of options. One of the options of these are changing the background to white/black or sepia. When clicked, the background changes instantly and reading can be continued. I am pretty new to Android or programming as such, so I am guessing restarting the current activity would mean loading the ebook all over again. Is that so?